# Можно ли в предложении SET устанавливать новые значения для полей нескольких таблиц?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Недавно начинаю изучать SQL, появился следующий вопрос из теста:

СУБД используется Microsoft SQL Server.

Можно ли в предложении SET устанавливать новые значения для полей нескольких таблиц:

а) да;

б) при наличии связи между таблицами;

в) нет;

г) только, если таблицы одинаковы по структуре;

Comment: В тесте написано, какая СУБД имеется в виду?  Чую, тут будут различия между ними.

Comment: тест по SQL в общем, не указывали какая СУБД имеется в виду.

Comment: SET clause может использоваться в нескольких типах запросов. Поэтому столь неконкретный вопрос, вообще без уточнения СУБД и типа запроса, лишён смысла.

Comment: В общем ответ скорее нет, так как в большинстве СУБД (если мы допускаем запрос без субзапросов), то за 1 запрос можно поменять несколько полей одной таблицы, но не наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

в) Нет. В одном запросе можно обновить только поля одной таблицы.

Вот [пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36727ef806ef5658a233337e7fd671b0), и попробуйте там поля из разных таблиц обновить, не получится. Только так:

```
update tab1 set col1 = 'ccc'
from tab1 inner join tab2 on tab2.id = tab1.id
```

Ссылка [на документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Стандартная очередь проверок порой не показывает целевой вопрос (ох, когда сами столкнетесь с этим, поймете))) Плюс ко всему, на ресурсе принято давать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @DaemonHK Изменил, развернул достаточно?

Comment: Да, теперь моя душа спокойна, думаю, многих членов Сообщества тоже)

Answer (score 2):

Немного не по теме: в MySQL и MariaDB это делается при помощи JOIN.

```
tab_1: name = 'a', type = 'c'

tab_2: name = 'b', type = 'c'
```

Поехали жоска джоином:

```
update tab_1 join tab_2 using(type) set tab_1.name = 'aaa', tab_2.name = 'bbb' where type = 'c'
```

Поехали ваще без джоинов:

```
update tab_1, tab_2 set tab_1.name = 'aaa', tab_2.name = 'bbb' where tab_1.type = tab_2.type
```

)))

Comment: Желательно приводить пример реализации, а то сейчас на вопросе 2 противоположных по смыслу ответа.

Comment: @DaemonHK зырь )

Comment: @Федот добро пожаловать в мир запросов к БД )))

Comment: Стиль подачи, конечно, не ахти) Но именно так и нужно отвечать на вопросы. Развернуто, с примерами и пояснениями))

Comment: @DaemonHK ))) одним глазом писал)

Comment: @АртёмРыженький Спасибо за приглашение! Откройте и второй глаз и посмотрите ваш странный мир [запросов](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=152e8c22d747760e8356eb4e19bf144d).

Comment: @Федот давай теперь ты открой ))) [запросы](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=152e8c22d747760e8356eb4e19bf144d)

Comment: @АртёмРыженький Открыл. А теперь внимательно  посмотри вопрос - Microsoft SQL Server. Стоит ли объяснять разницу между ним и MySQL? Ха-ха, удаляй  ответ :))

Comment: @Федот а теперь внимательно посмотри когда дан мой ответ и когда автор делал уточнение, какая СУБД его интересует, ха-ха, давай когда в Microsoft SQL Server появится такой функционал ты сюда обязательно зайдёшь, чтобы удалить свой ответ :)) Давай так: мне просто в репу уже настучали - репа понизится, если вопрос с репой удалю? Если нет, то удалю ответ, ок

Comment: @АртёмРыженький Посмотрел, 21 авг. 21:30 [автор добавил СУБД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1168808/2). Ну ладно, давай мир, репа снимется если удалишь. Добавь в ответ ссылку с фиддла, и что это для мускула, и всё будет гут.

Comment: @Федот напишу просто, что это для мускула, ок, стукнул тебе десяточку :)